# wp8.1 listview datatemplate with grid

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Hi i have one listview with datatemplate with items 
     
                          Visibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                       Height="{Binding ElementName=stck_main,Path=ActualHeight}"
                         SelectionChanged="lst_OutletDetails_SelectionChanged">

```
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0" />
                        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>-->
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>


                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100"  >
                            <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Width="5"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="grd_items_outletdetails" Background="{Binding ItemBackground}" Width="{Binding ElementName=lst_OutletDetails,Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OutletName}" Margin="5,0,0,0"  Foreground="White" FontSize="22"  Grid.Row="0" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastVisitedDate}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"
                                           Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,40,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />


                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OutletCode}" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="18"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"/>

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,20,0" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <TextBlock Text="ISM:" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="18"  />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ISMName}" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,20,0" FontSize="18"  />
                                </StackPanel>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Route}"  Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Foreground="White" />

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="5,0,20,0" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                  <TextBlock Text="Status:" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,20,0" FontSize="18"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>


                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

i want to change the colors of few items ,,, using mvvm pattern in windows phone 8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your question (problem) outside the codeblocks, it's hidden now.
What do you exactly want to do? Do you want to change the background color of few elements on your listbox? Describe it more precisely :)

As I can see you bind the `ItemBackground` property to your Grid `Background`, so just change the `ItemBackground` of elements you want in your source collection.